# Passing nested values to class methods in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to web scraping, please pardon the possible vagueness in my terminology :|

A snippet of an HTML page that I'm trying to write a spider for:

```
<h3>2019 General Meetings</h3>
<p><strong>Group 20:</strong> <br />Wednesday, June 5, 9 a.m. <br /> Bank &amp; Trust, 10000 E. Western Ave.</p>
<p>Wednesday, July 11, 9 a.m. <br />Bank &amp; Trust, 10000 E. Western Ave.</p>
<p><strong>Group 20:</strong> <br />Monday, July 8, 9 a.m.<br />Hubbard, 1740 W. 199th St.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p></div>
```

The logic I'm trying to follow is: 
I have the <h3>  which is the "top level" (or at least I consider it to be), there are other h3's on the page, so I need to make sure only this <h3> gets passed to the following parsers.

For the above, I'm using

```
response_items = response.xpath("//h3[contains(@h3, 'General Meetings')]")
```

And I think I have it working. (But needs more testing to make certain.)

I need to pass each of the <p> to a respective parser within the class, and each should return a required piece of information about the meeting, e.g
`_parser_date` will return the date, `_parser_address` will return the address, and do on.

I'm coming short on finding the correct scrapy/xpath syntax for this. Following https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html I can't get this to work quite well.

I'm particularly interested in each parser to "pick up" on a pattern within the <p>'s it's going to parse, and if it's a date pattern then format it, and return.
If it's a location pattern.. and so on.

I'm trying to avoid using `re.()`, unless you'd advise it's the right thing to do here.
Any insights would be most welcome,
Thank you.

Comment: `<h3>` is *not* the top level (aka parent), of those `<p>` nodes, it's a sibiling. Ideally you should select the node that wraps around the h3 and p, if possible. For the snippet you posted you could use `//h3[contains(text(), 'General Meetings')]/following-sibling::p[1]` and change the index accordingly. However in the actual page I imagine this won't work well. I suggest you post a bigger snippet of the HTML.

Comment: I understand. I think I have more reading to do about xpath/xml/html :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for p_node in response.xpath('//h3[contains(., 'General Meetings')]/following-sibling::p[position() < last()]'):
    address = p_node.xpath('./text()[last()]).get()
    date = p_node.xpath('./text()[last() - 1]).get()
```

I used `position() < last()` to skip last empty `<p>` and also I'm parsing data from the end.